# Update a Field on Insert Based On Others in SQL

Tags: sql-server, triggers

When data is insert into tableA I need to change Column23 based upon values of Column28, Column29 and Column30. I cannot change the insert statement as this done by a 3rd party application.

```
On insert if Column28 = '08', Column29 = 1 and Column30 <> 3 set Column23 = 3
On insert if Column28 = '05', Column29 = 1 and Column30 <> 2 set Column23 = 2
On insert if Column28 = '04', Column29 = 1 and Column30 <> 1 set Column23 = 1
```

I assume a trigger would be best to handle this as the data needs changing straight after insertion.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not just do `insert...select...`? What on earth does it have 261 columns for anyway?

Comment: What does triggers have to do with this? Your question was about an `INSERT`, not a `TRIGGER`.

Comment: @Larnu It's currently handled using a stored procedure and a 1 min sql agent job but the data can be changed before the agent job fires. Hence why I thought this would be done via a trigger.

Comment: But you don't mentioned triggers in your question at all, you just ask about how to set the values in an `INSERT`. And you control the values you insert at the `INSERT` point *in* the `INSERT` statement. To be honest, the above reads like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) as it seems that you what you do need to change *is* the `INSERT` statement, and possibly your design as well.

Comment: @Larnu I cannot change the insert statement which is why I need to handle it else where.

Comment: Then you should be talking to whomever can, @Testsubjec , fix the application; that's the real solution.

Comment: And if you want help with a trigger, grab a tutorial or the documentation and have a go and see how far you can get then ask when stuck.